# Works on simulator, but doesn't work on Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I developed an application that runs fine on the Simulator, but crashes on the iPhone.
Actually, the app doesn't crash on initialization, but when I change to another view.
I realized, the application just crash when i change to a view that doesn't have a Segue. For instance, on executing

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

**The crash is:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryBoard' in bundle NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/EE37B62E-E345-4F69-A6F0-3F56CB23F7BF/tableview.app> (loaded)'
```

First throw call stack:

```
(0x357d788f 0x37b7e259 0x335835fb 0x1ccad 0x332bd93d 0x33337627 0x352f1933 0x357aba33 0x357ab699 0x357aa26f 0x3572d4a5 0x3572d36d 0x373c9439 0x33239cd5 0x9a25 0x99c0)

terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 3):

Difficult to say for certain, but the fact that the filename is 'MainStoryBoard' (with capital B) makes this sound like a case sensitivity issue. The Mac (and therefore the Simulator) is not case sensitive, but the iPhone itself is, meaning incorrect case sensitivity runs fine until you put it on an actual device. Run a project-wide search for MainStoryboard and make sure the filename and any references to it in code match up perfectly.

Comment: Case sensitivity issues have caused me a lot of headaches, glad I could help :D  Remember to list an answer as the accepted answer by selecting the tick underneath it when viewing the question